# Getting Invalid column name error when using a CTE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have this query to update a column in a staging table.

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        [dbo].[udf_Text](A.column1) AS [NewColumn1], 
        column1 AS [OldDesc],
        ID_1, ID_2
    FROM
        [staging].[Table] A
) 
UPDATE [staging].[Table]
SET [staging].[Table].column1 = CTE.[NewColumn1]
WHERE [staging].[Table].ID_1 = CTE.ID_1 AND ID_2 = CTE.ID_2
```

What I'm trying to do is to pull the old column in the CTE and then update it with the new column that has the UDF applied to it. so I wrote this query and I'm getting this error.

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 45
> Invalid column name 'NewColumn1'

How can I achieve this or maybe if there's a better way around this?

Comment: I think you might be missing a from clause

Comment: What exactly do you think `CTE_AR` references? Your CTE is named `CTE`!

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually **reference** the CTE in your `UPDATE` statement:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    ....
) 
UPDATE t
SET column1 = CTE.[NewColumn1]
FROM [staging].[Table] t
INNER JOIN CTE ON t.ID_1 = CTE.ID_1 AND t.ID_2 = CTE.ID_2
```

Answer (score 0):

Although, as mentioned by others, you need to join the CTE to be able to reference it, in this particular example **you can actually update the CTE directly**.

This assumes that `ID_1` and `ID_2` uniquely identify a row

```sql
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        [dbo].[udf_Text](A.column1) AS [NewColumn1], 
        column1 AS [OldDesc],
        ID_1, ID_2
    FROM
        [staging].[Table] A
) 
UPDATE CTE
SET column1 = CTE_AR.[NewColumn1]
```

The CTE needs to follow rules for [updatable views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#updatable-views)

Comment: The above query gives me this error
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
The multi-part identifier "[staging].[Table].column1" could not be bound.
for some reason it sounds easier to be done but SQL not liking the structure of whatever query I'm writing to do this.

Comment: Whoops sorry fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Why not just write the logic directly?

```
UPDATE [staging].[Table]
    SET [staging].[Table].column1 = [dbo].[udf_Text](A.column1);
```